# How to escape the null object reference?

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception

so I was creating an application in Android Studio and I wanted to use RecyclerView to display a list of CardView objects. However, the data for that list is snapshotted from Firebase Firestore and when I log out the user from the application, the addSnapshotListener and getDocumentChanges methods invoke an error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference
```

How do I fix this? I will include the whole list rewrite method bellow:

```
private void rewriteLessonList() {

        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {

            firestoreCheck.collection("Lessons").document(userID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        lesson_list_rewrite_inner = new ArrayList<>();

                        firestoreCheck.collection("Lessons").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                                lesson_list.clear();

                                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                        LessonPost lessonPostMain = doc.getDocument().toObject(LessonPost.class);
                                        lesson_list.add(lessonPostMain);

                                        lessonRecyclerAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        timeWaste();
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error loading lessons ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `queryDocumentSnapshots == null`. So you can add a new check.

```
if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
    List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();
    if (documentChanges != null) {
        for (DocumentChange doc : documentChanges ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing *@Nullable* anotation by *@NonNull* in method declaration.